# Как в c# задать центр вращения Graphics.RotateTransform?

Tags: c#, graphics

Хочу разместить на PictereBox текст под определенным углом.
При использовании *Graphics.RotateTransform* текст, который вращаю, пропадает из поля.

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle);
Type = new Font("Arial", 13);
g.RotateTransform(90);
g.DrawString("y, мм", Type, Brushes.Black, 20, 20);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два способа повернуть на угол вокруг указанной точки. 
Допустим:

```
angle - угол, на который нужно повернуть
(x, y) - точка, вокруг которой осуществляется поворот.
```

Первый с использованием RotateTransform:

```
g.TranslateTransform(dx, dy);   // перемещаемся на нужную точку
g.RotateTransform(angle);     // поворачиваем элемент
g.TranslateTransform(-dx, -dy); // возвращаемся назад
```

Второй с использованием матрицы преобразований:

```
using (var newTransform = g.Transform)   // для полученной матрицы нужно вызвать Dispose
{
    var transform = g.Transform;
    try
    {
        g.Transform = newTransform;

        newTransform.RotateAt(angle, new PointF(x, y));
    }
    finally
    {
        g.Transform = transform;
    }
}
```

Comment: "g.TranslateTransform(x0, y0); // возвращаемся назад" А как узнать x0 и y0?

Comment: посмотрел документацию. там указывается смещение от текущей позиции ((0; 0) в вашем примере. тогда dx = x, а dy = y). поправил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите. Вращение происходит вокруг локального начала координат. Поэтому чтобы сделать вращение вокруг, например, центра, нужно переместить рисунок на вектор, соединяющий начало с центром вращения, и потом назад.

```
var cx = Width/2.0;
car cy = Height/2.0;

g.TranslateTransform(cx, cy);
g.RotateTransform(90);
g.TranslateTransform(-cx, -cy);
```

(Если вы учили алгебру, это называется *сопряжённый элемент группы преобразований*.)

Comment: Как узнать локальное начало координат?